# SendGrid email attachments included in message body

Tags: gmail, sendgrid, email-attachments

Problem sending attachment (csv file) with sendgrid

Hello when I send emails with sendgrid (via Gmail.com) with an attachment (a CSV file) the content of the file is found in the body of the email!

like that :

`Please find attached the monthly statement of MAY2023.csv --frontier Content-Type: text/csv; charset="UTF-8" Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MAI2023.csv 1,5,2023,0,0,10,V.Inst.,0.00,0.00 1,5,2023,0,0,26,V.Inst.,0.00,0.00 1,5,2023 ,0,0,41,V.Inst.,0.00,0.00 1.5,2023,0,0.57,V.Inst.,0.00,0.00 1.5,2023,0,1,12,V.Inst.,0.00,0.00 1.5 ,2023,0,1,27,V.Inst.,0.00,0.00 1.5,2023,0,1.43,V.Inst.,0.00,0.00 1.5,2023,0,1.58,V.Inst.,0.00 0.00 1,5,2023,0,2,13,V.Inst.......`

And not attached!

Is there a parameter or is it a malfunction of SendGrid, or Gmail?

With another ISP like laposte.net (without going through Sendgrid) it works fine.

PS: these emails are sent by Arduinos (hive monitoring) via Renzo Mischianti's EMailSender2 library

THANK YOU

```
/* sendgrid */
uint16_t SMTP_PORT2 = 587;                                  
const char* smtp_server2 = "smtp.sendgrid.net";                
const char* email_login2 = "apikey";     
const char* email_from2 = "myadress@gmail.com";      
const char* name_from2 =expediteur.c_str();                 
const char* email_password2 = "SG...............d2sq4hXfg";                  


const char* arrayOfEmail[] = {"sendgridtesting@gmail.com" }; 
byte nb_Destinaire_Mail = 1;                                                        

EMailSender::FileDescriptior fileDescriptor[piecejointe];  
                  
                     
fileDescriptor[0].filename = NomFichierMensuel;
fileDescriptor[0].url = NomFichierMensuel;
fileDescriptor[0].mime = "text/csv";
fileDescriptor[0].encode64 = false;
fileDescriptor[0].storageType = EMailSender::EMAIL_STORAGE_TYPE_SD;
                  
EMailSender::Attachments attachs = {piecejointe, fileDescriptor};
```

Comment: What code / framework do you use to send the email?

Comment: Hello, thank you I just put the Arduino code, but this one works very well with another ISP (laposte.net)...
THANKS